# Backup and Restore: Problem during Importing Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I took a logical backup of a database as the SYS user and restored it to a database on other machine as the System user.

On the destination server, the structure of a few tables wasn't the same as on the source server.  There were a few extra columns in a few tables in the source database.  When I tried to import the dump file into the destination database, it didn't import correctly.  The table structure was still the old one and there was no data/old data in any of those tables.  When I deleted those tables and tried importing the same dump file again, it imported successfully-- the new table structure along with the new data was present.

I can't figure out  where was I wrong (since im new to it).  Do I always need to delete the tables which are altered and import the database?  Or is there a way to overwrite the old structure of the table with the new structure?

I'm using Oracle 11g.

This was the export command I used to take backup

```
exp lsone/lsone file=newbkp.dmp log=newlog.log owner=lsone
```

This command was the one to import the dump file

```
imp system/manager file=newbkp.dmp log=import.log fromuser=lsone touser=dev
```

Would appreciate your reply!!

Comment: When you say that you "deleted" the tables, do you really mean that you dropped the tables rather than merely deleting the data in the tables?

Answer (score 0):

> *Do I always need to delete the tables which are altered and import the database?*

Yes that is advisable, especially if you *know* the structure has changed.

If the structures are the same you can run the `exp` command with the parameter `ignore=yes`, but you still need to get rid of all the rows in the tables - which is nearly the same amount of work as to drop all tables.

> *Or is there a way to overwrite the old structure of the table with the new structure?*

No